# Set ssl version with Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an old server that only accepts SSLv3 and SSLv3. I want to set the ssl version when I make the request.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(@request.uri.host, @request.uri.port)
http.use_ssl = @request.uri.scheme == 'https'
http.ssl_version = :SSLv3
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

leads to

```
[2020-09-10T05:37:14.452819 #254200] FATAL -- :   
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version):
```

I tried other combinations but failed.
`http.ssl_version = :SSLv3`
`http.ssl_version = "SSLv3"`

How can I set the specific ssl version? I am using Ruby 2.7.1 and Rails 6. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most current versions of OpenSSL, the support for SSLv3 is statically disabled during compile time since the protocol is widely considered as insecure. As such, there is often no way to still use SSLv3 on those OpenSSL versions.

If SSLv3 is a hard requirement, you will likely have to first compile your own OpenSSL version with suitable configuration options, followed by the compilation of your Ruby against your custom OpenSSL.

Preferably, you should either update the server to support newer more secure protocols (such as TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3) or ask the operator of the server to do so.

Comment: The server's running Win 2003 server! Will probably look at upgrading the server to at least 2008 R2, as it seems to support TLSv1.2. Thanks.

Comment: Just an update : Upgrading old server was a pain, so ended up using reverse proxy through a newer server that accepted newer TLS versions.